# Can't get .txt save file to save information properly

Tags: java

Hey guys I've just started learning Java (first language) and I'm probably asking a very simple question but I've been stuck writing a basic address book. My problem is that when I am saving to the .txt file each time I leave a space when answering one of my questions it saves it as a new line in the .txt file and I can't figure out why.

Sorry if this is a waste of time for some of you but I would be really grateful if someone were to look over it quickly.

Thanks a lot!

```
    Scanner address = new Scanner(System.in);
    Writer saveFile = new FileWriter("addressSave.txt");



    // Address Questions.

    String Name;
    System.out.println("Whats your name?");
    Name = address.next();
    saveFile.write (Name + "\r\n");

    String country;
    System.out.println("What country do you live in?");
    country = address.next();
    saveFile.write (country + "\r\n");

    String Area;
    System.out.print("Okay now what area do you live in?" +  "\r\n");
    Area = address.next();
    saveFile.write (Area + "\r\n");

    String Road;
    System.out.print("Okay now what road do you live on?" +  "\r\n");
    Road = address.next();
    saveFile.write (Road + "\r\n");

    String Postcode;
    System.out.print("And finally whats your postcode?" +  "\r\n");
    Postcode = address.next();
    saveFile.write (Postcode + "\r\n");


    if(address != null) 
        address.close();

    // Closing save file


    saveFile.close();
    System.exit(1);
```

Comment: Adding `"\r\n"` every time you write to the file will add a carriage return and a new line to your file.

Comment: All of your prompts are written as the value followed by a newline, so your space or even a blank response would also be written to the file, followed by a newline.  Since you are new to Java, you may not be aware that adding "\r\n" to a string adds a newline.  If you don't want this behavior, you need to add a test to your code that checks to see if the response is blank or whitespace, and if it is, skip writing it out to the file.  This would be a good function - don't repeat the code for the test every time you need it.

Comment: \n is good enough to add a newline on unix/linux, \r\n is a Windows line ending.

Comment: You can make your code less platform dependent if you get the platforms line separator from the system properties: `String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");`. Then use `lineSeparator` instead of `"\r\n"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the comments correctly mention you shouldn't use `\r\n` (`\n` should be enough, or use `PrintWriter` and `println(...)` instead), I think your mistake is to use `address.next()` instead of more appropriate `address.nextLine()`.

Comment: Thankyou guys this is my first question on this site and you've all been so helpful, got it sorted straight away thanks to you guys!